# Rviz data Saving format

Tags: ros, rviz, data

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I would  like to  know  how to  save Rviz results  in text file or any other format.Could any body  give me feedback.

[Screenshot from 2016-06-24 11_44_20.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14676518479803662.png)

I want to save these  x,y,z and alpha,beta,ghamma results as a text  file.

Could any  body  let me know  how can I do that

Best
Taher[Screenshot from 2016-06-24 11_44_20.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14676524199348754.png)(/upfiles/14676522631575838.png)

---

Edit: Hello Janidu
I used  quite a  long time  where  exactly  I can find these option  to  solve this  problem .Yes  It  will  not be automatically  saved  Markers  pose.I have  to  give  command or  time steps  to save my Markers Pose
I means  How  Can I  do that.
I  carefully checked Rviz  user  manual and other options  but  did  not find yet the way to  save  pose results  in text file or  any  format.
Would  you mind to give  link or  any thing that  I  should maintain. I  am  using  ROS  Indigo.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238742/rviz-data--saving--format/) by [btaher20](https://answers.ros.org/users/25814/btaher20/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-07-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2016-07-05**:
You can't do it in Rviz. Simple as that. Identify what data you want to save first. Then identify which topics these data are published to. Then save it to a rosbag or pipe as Felix has said. I hope it's clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rviz just displays results, right? I don't think it computes those results by itself (please correct me if I'm wrong). So what you can do is, finding out the topics that publish your marker poses and record them in rosbags.

---

Originally posted by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) with karma: 849 on 2016-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1